# NASM: why do two subsequent printf calls return different data

Tags: nasm

I am kind of beginner in NASM, but can't understand why this NASM code produces two different outputs although the printf calls are one after another and nothing is changed in between:

```
SECTION .data
        formatout: db "%d %d", 10, 0
SECTION .text
        global main
        extern printf
main:
        mov ecx, 2
        mov edx, 1

        push edx
        push ecx
        push formatout
        call printf
        add esp, 12

        push edx
        push ecx
        push formatout
        call printf
        add esp, 12


        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80
```

Thanks!

Comment: With [CDECL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) calling convention EAX, ECX, and EDX are potentially clobbered when making a function call (They are consider caller saved registers). Likely ECX and EDX no longer have the values you expect after the first call to `printf`

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clear :)